# How can I extract all global variables from a script and get each data type in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, reflection, reference

I like to capture all global variables from an external Perl script with Perl. Currently I am hanging around the type detection.

How to determine the correct data type ('', 'SCALAR', 'HASH', 'ARRAY', 'CODE')?

Parser script:

```
my %allVariables = ();
{
     do "scriptToBeParsed.pl";
     foreach my $sym ( keys %main:: ) {
         # Get all normal variables and scalar/hash/array references:
        if ( ref( *{"$sym"} ) =~ m/^(?:|SCALAR|HASH|ARRAY)$/ ) {
            $allVariables{"$sym"} = *{"$sym"};
        }
    }
}
```

Script to be parsed:

```
$someVariable1 = 'Yes, I like to be captured';
$otherVariable2 = \'And I also want to be captured';
%anotherVariable3 = ( 'Capture' => 'me' );
@lameVariable4 = ( 'Capture', 'me' );
$fooVariable5 = { 'Capture' => 'me' };
$barVariable6 = [ 'Capture', 'me' ];
$subVariable7 = sub { return "Don't capture me!" };
sub dontCaptureMe { return "Don't capture me!" }
```

In my example `ref( *{"$sym"} )` returns always 'GLOB' (of course).

Comment: the only 'global' in your to-be-parsed script is `sub dontCaptureMe`; all the others are lexicals...

Comment: you're right, @pavel. My example was incorrect. Edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the has-like access of the typeglob, which is explained in Chapter 8 of brian d foy's *Mastering Perl* on page 131f.

```
package test;
no strict;
no warnings; 

$someVariable1 = 'Yes, I like to be captured';
$otherVariable2 = \'And I also want to be captured';
%anotherVariable3 = ( 'Capture' => 'me' );
@lameVariable4 = ( 'Capture', 'me' );
$fooVariable5 = { 'Capture' => 'me' };
$barVariable6 = [ 'Capture', 'me' ];
$subVariable7 = sub { return "Don't capture me!" };
sub dontCaptureMe { return "Don't capture me!" }

say $dontCaptureMe;
my %allVariables = ();
{
  do "scriptToBecomeParsed.pl";
  foreach my $sym ( keys %test:: ) {
    for (qw( SCALAR HASH ARRAY CODE IO)) {
      if (*{"$sym"}{$_}) {
        $allVariables{$_}->{"$sym"} = *{"$sym"}{$_};
      }
    }
  }
}

print Data::Dumper::Dumper \%allVariables;
```

This will produce the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'CODE' => {
                      'dontCaptureMe' => sub { "DUMMY" }
                    },
          'ARRAY' => {
                       'lameVariable4' => [
                                            'Capture',
                                            'me'
                                          ]
                     },
          'HASH' => {
                      'anotherVariable3' => {
                                              'Capture' => 'me'
                                            }
                    },
          'SCALAR' => {
                        'someVariable1' => \'Yes, I like to be captured',
                        '__ANON__' => \undef,
                        'subVariable7' => \sub { "DUMMY" },
                        'dontCaptureMe' => \undef,
                        'otherVariable2' => \\'And I also want to be captured',
                        'BEGIN' => \undef,
                        'barVariable6' => \[
                                              'Capture',
                                              'me'
                                            ],
                        'anotherVariable3' => \undef,
                        'lameVariable4' => \undef,
                        'fooVariable5' => \{
                                              'Capture' => 'me'
                                            }
                      }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

like you said

> ref( *{"$sym"} ) returns always 'GLOB' (of course).

Because perl stores everything in the symbol table in a glob, it is impossible to tell which data type something is. This is because in perl it is perfectly valid to have an array, scalar, hash or whatever else with the same name... because of this, perl stores everything in globs to avoid collisions. What you could do is loop through all of the symbols in the symbol table and test each glob against all the possible things that it could be (the set isn't too large) and see which ones are set.

Alternatively, a more practical approach might be to just load the perl script as text and parse for `$`, `%`, `@`, `sub`, `open` (filehandle) to see what type everything is.

Comment: I think you meant "alternatively" rather than "alliteratively". At least, I don't see an awesomely acceptable alliterative answer to the question in your final paragraph.

Comment: Well, at least I learned something out of it. I had no idea "alliteratively" was even a word.

Comment: I was almost tempted to just make the rest of that answer an alliteration instead of just changing it to "alternatively" but I feel like that would've ruined a quality answer

Comment: @John I don't think that is even possible. I challenge you to do it and to post it at [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/). :D

Comment: it's an adjective to describe an alliteration, which is the repetition of a sound in words that are placed closely together. Like "Deep into that darkness peering, long I stood there wondering, fearing, Doubting, dreaming dreams no mortal ever dared to dream before." The repetition of the "D" makes it an alliteration.